# Python3 - error importig module

Tags: python, import, module

[image]

When I try to import:

load.py:

```
from .column import Column
```

I get error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.column'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Help?

Comment: How do you start load.py?

Comment: Shouldn't it simply be `from column import Column`?

Comment: @xzoert It's a part of Django project, but I start only module with python load.py

@le_wofl I think in Python3 it must be `.`.

Comment: No, that's ok, it's a relative import. But I think you'll have to start the file as module, like `python -m load`, and not as a script.

Comment: However, I tried everything, but it just doesn't recognize column.py. I can import modules from other packages, but this one keeps throwing error.

Comment: @xzoert Now I get: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: oh... maybe starting from the parent dir using `python -m load.load`? sorry, i'm not an expert too!